# python regex token capture

Tags: python, regex

I need to capture small code (token) from html with regex, I'm writing code with BeautifulSoup but it is not possible to compile with py2exe, so for this I need a solution wihth regex. My html code is this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="wp-upload-form" action="http://localhost/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin">
        <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="a7a9167537"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload">     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="pluginzip">Plugin zip file</label>
        <input type="file" id="pluginzip" name="pluginzip">
        <input type="submit" name="install-plugin-submit" id="install-plugin-submit" class="button" value="Install Now" disabled="">    </form>
```

and I need to capture this code: `a7a9167537`

I wrote this regex but it did not work:

```
id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="(.*)"
```

Comment: Could you put your code or at least the line with youre regex ?

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
wp_token = soup.find("input", {'id': "_wpnonce"}).attrs['value']

whit regex i not know, need help :(

Comment: There are other methods of parsing this that are *much* better than [using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761). The standard library includes e.g. [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it with the [HTMLParser module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) instead of regex:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

s = r"""<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="wp-upload-form" action="http://localhost/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin">
        <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="a7a9167537"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload">     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="pluginzip">Plugin zip file</label>
        <input type="file" id="pluginzip" name="pluginzip">
        <input type="submit" name="install-plugin-submit" id="install-plugin-submit" class="button" value="Install Now" disabled="">    </form>"""


class CodeFinder(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "input":
            attrs = dict(attrs)
            if 'id' in attrs and attrs['id'] == '_wpnonce':
                print("The  value is: {}".format(attrs['value']))

parser = CodeFinder()
parser.feed(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe something like this?

```
print(re.search(r'(?=<input(?=[^>]+id="_wpnonce")(?=[^>]*name="_wpnonce")[^>]+value="([^"]+)")', html).group(1))
```

In BeautifulSoup, you can use:

```
print(soup.find("input", {"id": "_wpnonce", "name": "_wpnonce"})['value'])
```

Comment: i like your regex, bat need add _wpnonce in regex because the complete page have more inputs !

Comment: @kingcope Oh, okay, added those to the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    import re
    searchText = '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="wp-upload-form" action="http://localhost/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin"><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="a7a9167537"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload">     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="pluginzip">Plugin zip file</label><input type="file" id="pluginzip" name="pluginzip"><input type="submit" name="install-plugin-submit" id="install-plugin-submit" class="button" value="Install Now" disabled="">    </form>'


    print re.sub("(.+name=\"_wpnonce\"\\ value=\"([\\d\\w]{10})\">.+)", "\\2", searchText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is `greedy` . Change it to `lazy`

Modified Regex : `(?<=id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value=")(.*?)"`

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI3bO6)

To get exactly the value, Use this regex : `(?<=id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value=").*?(?=")`

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dT9uY7)

Comment: print re.sub("(?<=id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value=")(.*?)"", text)
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Working correctly for me `re.sub(r'(?<=id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value=").*?(?=")','',text)`

Comment: @kingcope Have u got it ?

Comment: pastebin.com/ptPj7JEK not working, need print only this code : a7a9167537